# ICDF function in Matlab for Inverse Gaussian distribution

Tags: matlab, distribution, gaussian, cdf

I am trying to generate an inverse gaussian distribution using the ICDF function in matlab.  The parameters are:

mu = 4.68
lambda = 12286

I get the following error: *Warning: Divide by zero. This warning will be removed in a future release. Consider using DBSTOP IF NANINF when debugging.*

The issue is that the lambda is very high - when I try values of 50, 100, or 1000 there is no problem.  I'm working with Matlab 2006, so I can't use the makedist function.  Is there a way to avoid this error, or another function I can use to generate an inverse gaussian from a set of random probabilities?

Thanks!

Comment: Not clear what you want. Despite the names, the CDF of the [Inverse Gaussian Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution) is not the same thing inverse CDF of the Normal/Gaussian Distribution. There's a closed form for the former and you can use [`norminv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/norminv.html) for the latter.

Comment: My goal is to go from a random set of probabilities to the CDF of an inverse gaussian distribution described by the parameters mu and lambda.

Comment: Is `lambda` same as `sigma` ?